# Cannot find Japanese(Mozc) or Japanese(Anthy) in 20.04

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support, ibus, japanese

I want to type in japanese and therefore installed the Japanese language through settings. When I go to select the language, I can find the language Japanese, but cannot find the specific Japanese(Mozc) or Japanese(Anthy). I have run

`sudo apt-get install -y ibus-mozc` and
`sudo apt-get -y install ibus-anthy`
I've made sure I am on the latest version of IBUS as well.

I can see the Mozc-setup app in my applications window but cannot see the language itself.

What can I do to fix this?

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: Did you relogin after having installed `ibus-mozc` and `ibus-anthy`?

Comment: Yes, I have relogged in and restarted.Just as a clarification, ibus-mozc was already installed to the latest update.

Comment: I have the same question. There is no "Japanese (Mozc)" in my list of input sources despite having installed mozc-server and ibus-mozc

Answer (score 1):

Besides ibus-mozc and ibus-anthy you also need to install mozc-utils-gui for gui-support:

sudo apt-get install mozc-utils-gui